# How can I retrieve data using a live cd?

Tags: mount

My hard drive crashed, so I'm trying to retrieve the data on it using a Ubuntu live disk. I can access the desktop, and from there I open "files" and try to open "1.0 TB Volume," which (I think) is my hard drive. After a good bit of waiting, I receive the message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/282E16D52E169BBE: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/282E16D52E169BBE"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read hiberfil.sys: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I tried successfully made a system repair disk, but it spent about 8 hours "fixing" the problem and would have continued had I not shut it off. I don't really mind waiting, but after 8 hours I doubt it would have done anything.

What can I do about this? Please avoid using any words, phrases, or abbreviations that are too technical, as I am not very skilled with computers.

Comment: Please, register one account and ask for merging accounts in the contact us link below. That if [Pistos](http://askubuntu.com/users/193208/pistos) and [Pistos](http://askubuntu.com/users/193532/pistos) are the same person.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using Windows Recovery CD to repair the filesystem and then retrieve your data using the LiveCD. Apparently the filesystem is damaged, the best way to go is using `chkdsk /f` to repair the NTFS partition then try to recover the disk.

You should be sure that the drive is unmounted in Windows before shutting down. Other than that you could force your way through, but I presume your data is more important, and you wouldn't want to risk it for being hasty.